# Compare elements within a numpy array and add the equal elements to a new array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, compare

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl7IH.png)I have a numpy array with 907 rows and 2 columns, the columns correspond to x and y coordinates respectively. I want to write a code that make lists of all the elements that have the same Y. 
This is my code write now, I know it's wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
with open('Results.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    integers=np.array([list(map(int,x)) for x in readCSV]);

    val=0
    list_val=[]
    for i in integers:
        if i[1]==val:
        list_val=i   
        val += 1
```

Comment: could you provide a sample of the document?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl7IH.png

Comment: So you'd like multiple lists wherein each list contains a set of X,Y pairs with the same Y value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to answer this with minimum changes to your code. There are primarily three issues in your code:

1) You're using `val` to iterate over all possible values of the Y coordinate, but `val` doesn't actually take on every possible Y value. The code below works assuming that you only ever have non-negative integer Y values, and I've replaced `val` with `max_y` to provide a better sense of how to logically iterate over all possible Y coordinate values.

2) You'll need two loops: one to iterate over all possible Y values, and the inner loop to iterate over all the X,Y pairs in `integers`.

3) Since you have multiple possible values for Y, storing elements with the same Y value in a list would mean that you'd need multiple lists to achieve what you're trying. `list_val` in the code below is a list-of-lists, wherein each inner list is such that the X,Y pairs it stores have the same Y.

4) There is an incorrect indentation line 11 onwards in your code, but it's probably just an error while pasting.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
with open('this_csv.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    integers=np.array([list(map(int,x)) for x in readCSV])
    print(integers)
    max_y = np.amax(integers, axis=0)[1]
    list_val=[]
    for i in range(max_y+1):
        this_list = []
        for element in integers:
            if element[1]==i:
                this_list.append(element)
        if len(this_list)>0:
            list_val.append(this_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a much better idea now what to do.